# FindItemWithText in listview and show the result in textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have two listviews (`lvMessage and lvContact`) and one `textbox`.

lvMessage columns are `Number, DateAndTime, and Message`.
lvContact columns are `ID, Name, and ContactNumber`

I am trying to find the match of `lvMessage.subitem(Number)` in `lvContact.subitem(ContactNumber)` and if an item is found, then the textbox should display `lvContact.subitem(Name)` - from the row matched.

```
Private Sub ListView2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView2.Click
    Dim ChkContact As New ListViewItem
    ChkContact = lvContact.FindItemWithText("12344")
    If ChkContact IsNot Nothing Then
        txtContact.Text = lvContact.Items(0).SubItems(1).Text 'i have problem with this line
    Else
        txtContact.Text = "no match found"
    End If

End Sub
```

This code is working in finding the text. but the result is always the same when it find the text from lvContact.

**For example:** if the "1234" is found txtContact.text = (subitem(2) from the row matched)

Comment: your display the first row name text when its match it display that Name only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 txtContact.Text = lvContact.Items(0).SubItems(1).Text
```

To

```
txtContact.Text = ChkContact .SubItems(1).Text
```

Comment: one more question question... what if I change text inside [code] ChkContact = lvContact.FindItemWithText("12344")[/code] to ChkContact = lvContact.FindItemWithText(lvMessage.FocusedItem.Subitem(1).text) sin it is click event. but the result is "no match found"

Comment: change  lvMessage.FocusedItem.Subitem(1).text to lvMessage.FocusedItem.Subitem(0).text beacuse 1 is dateandtime 0 is number

Comment: Ooops.. sorry sir.. I also did that lvMessage.FocusedItem.Subitem(0).text... also.. lvMessage.SelectedItem(0).subitem(0).text... but the result is no match found. but if I insert the exact string it show the result okay.

Comment: `ListView2_Click` which listview event this?. And why you are not tried `ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged` Event. Am using like this its work for me   `Dim x As New ListViewItem
        x = ListView2.FindItemWithText(ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(0).Text)`

Comment: ok i'll try that one. and because of that. can I add a new column in listview1? lets say contactName(null value).. and when I select the row instead of putting the result in textbox... I will put it in my new column (contactName). is that possible sir?

Comment: yeah possible. do like this `lvMessage.FocusedItem.SubItems(3).Text=lvContact.FindItemWithText(lvMessage.FocusedItem.Subitem(1).text)`